# Extracting data from webpage using lxml XPath in Python

Tags: python, xpath, web-crawler, lxml, python-requests

I am having some unknown trouble when using xpath to retrieve text from an HTML page from lxml library.

The page url is www.mangapanda.com/one-piece/1/1

I want to extract the selected chapter name text from the drop down select tag. Now I just want the first option so the XPath to find that is pretty easy. That is :-

```
.//*[@id='chapterMenu']/option[1]/text()
```

I verified the above using Firepath and it gives correct data. but when I am trying to use lxml for the purpose I get not data at all.

```
from lxml import html
import requests

r = requests.get("http://www.mangapanda.com/one-piece/1/1")
page = html.fromstring(r.text)

name = page.xpath(".//*[@id='chapterMenu']/option[1]/text()")
```

But in name nothing is stored. I even tried other XPath's like :-

```
//div/select[@id='chapterMenu']/option[1]/text()
//select[@id='chapterMenu']/option[1]/text()
```

The above were also verified using FirePath. I am unable to figure out what could be the problem. I would request some assistance regarding this problem.

But it is not that all aren't working. An xpath that working with lxml xpath here is :-

```
.//img[@id='img']/@src
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had a look at the html source of that page and the content of the element with the id `chapterMenu` is empty.
I think your problem is that it is filled using javascript and javascript will not be automatically evaluated just by reading the html with `lxml.html`

You might want to have a look at this:
[Evaluate javascript on a local html file (without browser)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16375251/2677943)

Maybe you're able to trick it though... In the end, also javascript needs to fetch the information using a get request. In this case it requests: http://www.mangapanda.com/actions/selector/?id=103&which=191919

Which is json and can be easily turned into a python dict/array using the json library.
But you have to find out how to get the `id` and the `which` parameter if you want to automate this.

The id is part of the html, look for `document['mangaid']` within one of the script tags and `which` <s>can maybe stay 191919</s> has to be 0... <s>although I couldn't find it in any source</s> I found it, when it is 0 you will be redirected to the proper url.

So there you go ;)

Comment: Thanks I think this will work. I found out that we can even use QtWebkit which renders JS code. I tried using it and the html data I received contained all the chapters name. But the problem being that it takes more time to load.

Answer (score 0):

The source document of the page you are requesting is in a *default namespace*:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

even if Firepath does not tell you about this. The proper way to deal with namespaces is to *redeclare* them in your code, which means associating them with a *prefix* and then prefixing element names in XPath expressions.

```
name = page.xpath('//*[@id='chapterMenu']/xhtml:option[1]/text()',
   namespaces={'xhtml': 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'})
```

Then, the piece of the document the path expression above is concerned with is:

```
<select id="chapterMenu" name="chapterMenu"></select>
```

As you can see, there is no `option` element inside it. Please tell us what exactly you'd like to find.

Comment: I want to get the Chapter Name which we can see in the dropdown list. That is for the link I provided it will be "Chapter 1: Romance Dawn"

Comment: @Psycho_Coder Then, swenzel is quite right. This content is _not_ present in the source document. You can try this yourself by just opening the source and searching for e.g. "Romance".

Comment: Yes I saw that and @swenzel is quite correct. I wonder what I can do to get the chapter names. I making a MangaScrapper and I wanted it to be cool and simple. I thought there would exist better ways to do so rather than using a webdriver. One thing that I can do to meet my need is that from [this](http://www.mangapanda.com/alphabetical) page I get the url for Manga home and from there I extract the chapter URL. But that would require me to code extra things.

Comment: I've updated my answer... it might solve you problem now if you don't run into further js problems :D