# Requests won't get the text from web page?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I am trying to get the value of VIX from a webpage.

The code I am using:

```
raw_page = requests.get("https://www.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/vix_home_page.htm").text
soup = BeautifulSoup(raw_page, "lxml")
vix = soup.find("span",{"id":"vixIdxData"})
print(vix.text)
```

This gives me:

> ' '

If I see vix,

```
<span id="vixIdxData" style=" font-size: 1.8em;font-weight: bold;line-height: 20px;">/span>
```

On the site the element has text,

```
<span id="vixIdxData" style=" font-size: 1.8em;font-weight: bold;line-height: 20px;">15.785/span>
```

The `15.785` value is what I want to get by using requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data you're looking for, is not available in the page source. And `requests.get(...)` gets you only the page source without the elements that are dynamically added through JavaScript. But, you can still get it using `requests` module.

In the Network tab, inside the developer tools, you can see a file named `VixDetails.json`. A request is being sent to `https://www.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/VixDetails.json`, which returns the data in the form of JSON.

[image]

You can access it using the built-in `.json()` function of the `requests` module.

```
r = requests.get('https://www.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/VixDetails.json')
data = r.json()
vix_price = data['currentVixSnapShot'][0]['CURRENT_PRICE']
print(vix_price)
# 15.7000
```

Answer (score 0):

When you open the page in a web browser, the text (e.g., 15.785) is inserted into the `span` element by the [getIndiaVixData.js](https://www.nseindia.com/live_market/resources/js/getIndiaVixData.js) script.

When you get the page using `requests` in Python, only the HTML code is retrieved and no JavaScript processing is done. So, the span element stays empty.

It is impossible to get that data by solely parsing the HTML code of the page using `requests`.

Comment: @Sid you may find these useful: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43731197/evaluating-javascript-code-in-an-html-string-using-python
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16375251/evaluate-javascript-on-a-local-html-file-without-browser