# Unable to run selenium application using the Chrome driver on a server

Tags: python, linux, google-chrome, selenium, ubuntu

I've installed the latest version of Chrome driver which is 2.9 on a server on Ubuntu, with no display. I've setup everything else. When I run my python script, I get this:

```
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Runtime.executionContextCreated has invalid 'context': {"auxData":{"frameId":"3104.1","isDefault":true},"id":1,"name":"","origin":"://"}
  (Session info: chrome=54.0.2840.71)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.9.248304,platform=Linux 4.4.0-38-generic x86_64)
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

In general you can't run the Selenium with ordinary FF or Chrome without display.

As far as I know you have these options:

- Create virtual display on your server. What you are looking for is [VNC server](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VNC/Servers). You can check for example [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-vnc-on-ubuntu-16-04) tutorial. With this you can set-up how many virtual display on your sever you want and run the actual browsers using selenium in them.
- Use headless browser (which doesn't require display). I know that [PhantomJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7568899/does-selenium-support-headless-browser-testing) is often used. But it seems that Chrome is going to [support this soon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34170686/1768843). You can find plenty of the guides [on the google](https://www.google.com/search?q=selenium%20headless%20browser) on this topic.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please provide more information.You are saying that you use Chrome without display - that is not currently possible.

Comment: I didn't say that.

Comment: You said `with no display.` and didn't provide any other info how you solved this issue. It's hard to debug problems when you just throw one single error message. Does your browser start at all? ....