# How to run chrome driver in headless mode or in background

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I've been using chrome driver (with selenium webdriver), so far it never caused any issue, now for some requirement i want to run test cases in background. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this post [Any way to start Google Chrome in headless mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9210765/any-way-to-start-google-chrome-in-headless-mode), a new flag `--headless` is available in Chromium but Selenium is still to catch up as far as my limited googling skills tell me.

In the mean time you can explore HTMLUnitDriver for headless testing.

```
WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver((BrowserVersion.CHROME), true);
```

Comment: Thanks, but i don't want to use HtmlUnitDriver because all the test cases cant run ,if changes only drivers.it gives an error. like **org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate a node and so on.**

Answer (score 3):

Currently Chrome 59 supports headless mode. 
You just need to use those `chromeOptions` to use headless chrome in selenium.

```
chromeOptions.addArguments("--headless");
chromeOptions.addArguments("--disable-gpu");
```

You can refer below link for more details:
https://www.automation99.com/2017/07/how-to-use-chrome-headless-using.html