# Chrome not going headless

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium

this is my code:

```
    from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
driver.get("https://google.com/")
```

Yet the browser opens instead of going headless.
Some other arguments do seem to work like --start-maximized

Comment: What if you add `"--disable-gpu"` as well?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Any way to start Google Chrome in headless mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9210765/any-way-to-start-google-chrome-in-headless-mode)

Comment: I just tried this. It opens as a white screen.

Comment: There's advice at https://intoli.com/blog/running-selenium-with-headless-chrome/.

Comment: I read the blog. changed --headless to headless. still not working

Comment: You haven't mentioned what OS you're running. I see on https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome that headless won't be available on Windows until Chrome 60. Alas.

Comment: Oh that explains a lot... thanks

Comment: @BillBell Can you put that information as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is redundant but, since I've been asked to do it, https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome says that headless won't be available on Chrome for Windows until version 60.

Answer (score 0):

Headless won't be available on Windows untill Chrome 60.